# Selecting a word in a UITextView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

EDIT: I'm thinking I should use a UILabel instead of a UITextView as I don't want the highlight to use the system wide blue with 'copy/select all/define' popover.

I'm trying to build a custom text view, and I'm looking for some help with the right approach. I'm an iOS n00b so mainly looking for ideas about how best to approach the problem.

I want to build a custom text view, with the following behaviour:

1. View starts off small. If it receives a tap it grows (animated) to the size of the parent view as a modal window (top left picture, then top right picture)
2. In this large state, if an individual word is tapped, the word highlights in some fashion, and a delegate method is called passing a string containing the that was tapped (bottom left picture)

[image: New Text View]
<sub>(source: [telliott.net](http://telliott.net/static/NewTextView.png))</sub>

I suspect the complexity is going to be in the identifying the word that was clicked, so let's start there. I can think of a couple of ways of trying this:

1. Subclass UILabel. Add a touch gesture recognizer. When a touch is identified, get the (x.y) coordinates of the touch point somehow, look at the string the view is showing and figure out which word must have been pressed based on position. I can see this getting very complicated pretty quickly with word wrapping however. I'm not sure how to get the (x,y) coordinates of the touch (although I assume that's pretty simple), or how to get device dependant text widths for each character etc. I'd rather not go down this route unless someone can convince me it's not going to be horrible!
2. Subclass UIView, and fake the sentence by adding a UILabel for each word. Measure the width of each UILabel and lay them out myself. This seems like a more sensible approach, although I worry that laying out the text in this way is also going to be harder than I think by the time I start trying.

Is there a more sensible way? Can you retrieve a word that was touched in a UILabel some other way?

If I go for option 2, then I think the animation from small -> large text might be complicated, as the words will wrap in interesting ways. So I was thinking of having another subview - this time a UITextView - to hold the sentence in the small state. Animate this to large, then hide it, and at the same time reveal my UIView with one-view-per-word.

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

This got a lot easier for iOS 7, thanks to the addition of NSLayoutManager in CoreText. If you're dealing with a UITextView you can access the layout manager as a property of the view. In my case I wanted to stick with a UILabel, so you have to create a layout manager with the same size, i.e:

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:labelText];
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
CGRect bounds = label.bounds;
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:bounds.size];
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
```

Now you just need to find the index of the character that was clicked, which is simple!

```
NSUInteger characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location
                                                  inTextContainer:textContainer
                         fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
```

Which makes it trivial to find the word itself:

```
if (characterIndex < textStorage.length) {
  [labelText.string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length)
                                       options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                                    usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                      if (NSLocationInRange(characterIndex, enclosingRange)) {
                                        // Do your thing with the word, at range 'enclosingRange'
                                        *stop = YES;
                                      }
                                    }];
}
```

**Original Answer, which works for iOS < 7**

Thanks to @JP Hribovsek for some tips getting this working, I managed to solve this well enough for my purposes. It feels a little hacky, and likely wouldn't work too well for large bodies of text, but for paragraphs at a time (which is what I need) it's fine.

I created a simple UILabel subclass that allows me to set the inset value:

```
#import "WWLabel.h"

#define WWLabelDefaultInset 5

@implementation WWLabel

@synthesize topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.topInset = WWLabelDefaultInset;
        self.bottomInset = WWLabelDefaultInset;
        self.rightInset = WWLabelDefaultInset;
        self.leftInset = WWLabelDefaultInset;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {self.topInset, self.leftInset,
        self.bottomInset, self.rightInset};

    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Then I created a UIView subclass that contained my custom label, and on tap constructed the size of the text for each word in the label, until the size exceeded that of the tap location - this is the word that was tapped. It's not prefect, but works well enough for now.

I then used a simple NSAttributedString to highlight the text:

```
#import "WWPhoneticTextView.h"
#import "WWLabel.h"

#define WWPhoneticTextViewInset 5
#define WWPhoneticTextViewDefaultColor [UIColor blackColor]
#define WWPhoneticTextViewHighlightColor [UIColor yellowColor]

#define UILabelMagicTopMargin 5
#define UILabelMagicLeftMargin -5

@implementation WWPhoneticTextView {
    WWLabel *label;
    NSMutableAttributedString *labelText;
    NSRange tappedRange;
}

// ... skipped init methods, very simple, just call through to configureView

- (void)configureView
{
    if(!label) {
        tappedRange.location = NSNotFound;
        tappedRange.length = 0;

        label = [[WWLabel alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
        [label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setTopInset:WWPhoneticTextViewInset];
        [label setLeftInset:WWPhoneticTextViewInset];
        [label setBottomInset:WWPhoneticTextViewInset];
        [label setRightInset:WWPhoneticTextViewInset];

        [self addSubview:label];
    }


    // Setup tap handling
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    labelText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    [label setAttributedText:labelText];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // Get the location of the tap, and normalise for the text view (no margins)
        CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
        tapPoint.x = tapPoint.x - WWPhoneticTextViewInset - UILabelMagicLeftMargin;
        tapPoint.y = tapPoint.y - WWPhoneticTextViewInset - UILabelMagicTopMargin;

        // Iterate over each word, and check if the word contains the tap point in the correct line
        __block NSString *partialString = @"";
        __block NSString *lineString = @"";
        __block int currentLineHeight = label.font.pointSize;
        [label.text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [label.text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString* word, NSRange wordRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL* stop){

            CGSize sizeForText = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width-2*WWPhoneticTextViewInset, label.frame.size.height-2*WWPhoneticTextViewInset);
            partialString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", partialString, word];

            // Find the size of the partial string, and stop if we've hit the word
            CGSize partialStringSize  = [partialString sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:sizeForText lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

            if (partialStringSize.height > currentLineHeight) {
                // Text wrapped to new line
                currentLineHeight = partialStringSize.height;
                lineString = @"";
            }
            lineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", lineString, word];

            CGSize lineStringSize  = [lineString sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
            lineStringSize.width = lineStringSize.width + WWPhoneticTextViewInset;

            if (tapPoint.x < lineStringSize.width && tapPoint.y > (partialStringSize.height-label.font.pointSize) && tapPoint.y < partialStringSize.height) {
                NSLog(@"Tapped word %@", word);
                if (tappedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                    [labelText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:tappedRange];
                }

                tappedRange = wordRange;
                [labelText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:tappedRange];
                [label setAttributedText:labelText];
                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextView already has a delegate method that is triggered when selection change (note that moving the cursor within the textview is equivalent to changing the selection, the user doesn't actually need to 'select' any text for this to be called):

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
```

Whenever this is triggered, get the selectedRange like this:

```
NSRange range=textView.selectedRange;
```

If the user should be able to manually move the cursor or select an entire word, then you're pretty much done, otherwise, just add some processing around the string at selectedRange to figure out what the word around the cursor is, and highlight it with your method of choice.
You could for example enumerate all words in the textview, and figure out which one contains the current selection (or cursor), and select the entire word (which is a way of highlighting prior iOS 6)

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
NSRange range=textView.selectedRange;
[textView.text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [textView.text length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString* word, NSRange wordRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL* stop){
    NSRange intersectionRange=NSIntersectionRange(range,wordRange);
    if(interesectionRange.length>0){
        [textView setSelectedRange:wordRange];
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks JP, that's really useful and nearly what I need, although it only seems to work if the word is double tapped (this might be because my view isn't editable?). The highlighting is then done in the normal way with the 'copy/select all/define' pop up. This isn't what I want at all, and I don't think this behaviour can be modified. So I'm thinking I should probably use a UILabel instead. Do you have any thoughts on building this with a UILabel instead of a UITextView? Thanks :)

Comment: correct, the single tap would only work if your textview is editable. Highlighting can be done in the UITextView using NSAttributeString, but that would only work from iOS 6. Before that, the 'selection' method is the best workaround I know of. Do you already know the text to be displayed, or is the text defined at run time?

Comment: Text is defined at build time - it's static. I'm building a children's book, and I want the child to be able to tap a word and have that single word read back to them, to help learn how to read.

Comment: if it is at build time and very limited text, using other controls such as UILabel/UIButtons is a possible option, but for an entire book... you would have to create an algorithm that sizes and place those labels correctly, not an easy task..

Comment: What to do if we are tapping on an image containing text? I want the same thing but not for a text view, but for an image. ie,when the user taps on a point, the word should get highlighted. Does anyone have an idea?