# how to build a custom lookup for my dictionary App

Tags: ios, dictionary, lookup

I need to add a look-up for my dictionary app.All the other function of the app is working fine but i want to add a lookup function so that when the user tap a word in textview ,the word and its definition should appear on the lookup.

I had tried the motion sensor and other technique but could  solve my problem.

Any help or suggestion,i am stuck with this problem.

Comment: `UITextView` supports this by default. Select a word and the context menu appears. One of the menu items will be "Define".

Comment: @rmaddy :- i know that but in that define is not giving me the "definition". it only shows the word how to add the definition...

Comment: Selecting "Define" for me shows the definition of the currently selected word. What do you see?

Comment: @rmaddy :- it give me no definition and in manage section ...my dictionary is not showing.Mine is a customized dictionary so not on the list of the Manage section

Answer (score 0):

`UITapGestureRecognizer` is your friend here. Please take a look at following threads for implementation:

1. [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749049/perform-action-by-clicking-on-some-word-in-uitextview-or-uilabel)
2. [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318283/selecting-a-word-in-a-uitextview)
3. [Thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-in-ios)

BTW... Are you doing something different than `Define` action given by `UITextView`?

Comment: :- i try to use the define but it give only the word not the definition during simulation..what to now and yes i used the tap gesture and got the word but the result is not good.Thanks for the reply