# Find placement or order of word in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string, uitextview

I want to find the position of a word in a textview, so that if I have a textview with 300 words, and the user taps on word number 100, a UILabel reads, "100" and so on.

This seems like a helpful place to [start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318283/selecting-a-word-in-a-uitextview) to select a word in a textview. And I can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679564/get-no-of-words-in-swift-for-average-calculator) to get the word count of the textView. But beyond that I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for the position of the word as a rect in relation to the textview, or just want a callback with the string that is the word that was tapped?

Comment: No, I want the word number. If "dog" is word number 27 in the textview, I want to the UILabel to read "27" if the user taps on "dog"